# Pygame window does not close properly, after .py converted to .exe

Tags: python, pygame, pyinstaller, exe

I am having an issue quitting Pygame window properly. I confront the problem only when I convert the python file to exe using Auto Py to Exe, before conversion everyhting was working fine. The problem is, multiple new windows pop up when I try to close a window. That's what I got in the console:

```
pygame 2.0.0 (SDL 2.0.12, python 3.7.2)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
sys.exit() worked as expected
pygame 2.0.0 (SDL 2.0.12, python 3.7.2)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
pygame 2.0.0 (SDL 2.0.12, python 3.7.2)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
pygame 2.0.0 (SDL 2.0.12, python 3.7.2)
pygame 2.0.0 (SDL 2.0.12, python 3.7.2)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
pygame 2.0.0 (SDL 2.0.12, python 3.7.2)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
```

Here is the portion of code in which I quit the main game loop:

```
run = True

while run:
    clock.tick(25)  

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    update()

try:
    pygame.display.quit()
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()  
except SystemExit:
    print("sys.exit() worked as expected")
```

So, what might be causing the problem? Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT :**
Recently, I have noticed the problem disappears if I do not import Firebase module. I'm confused about why Firebase module works normally during the rest of the program but causes such an error only on exit.

I also replaced SystemExit with BaseException to see if I'm missing anything but SystemExit is the only one thrown on exit.

Answer (score 0):

The calls to quit pygame could be causing an exception stopping the sys.exit() call, prehaps catching any exeption in your try clause might illuminate the problem.

```
try:
    pygame.display.quit()
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()  
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

The multiple windows is odd, how are you running the .exe?